# Installing SQLDeveloper on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: installation, oracle-sqldeveloper, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install sqldeveloper on Ubuntu 16.04 with this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWnAizA1bYE&feature=youtu.be

In 8:00 is shows to enter the command: `chmod +x sql`

but after that I see a message: `chmod: cannot access 'sql': No such file or directory`

Someone had a similar problem? I tried: `sudo chmod +x sql`, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is pressing tab instead of enter. You should enter `chmod +x sqldeveloper.sh` in the terminal.

With tab you can autocomplete commands in the Ubuntu terminal. It's super useful if you are lazy and don't want to type everything.

Comment: Besure to mark the answer as correct so other people can find it more easily if they have the same problem

Comment: Ok, but in the next step when i try to change txt file with command: sudo gedit /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh, I take massage: ** (gedit:7584): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported. Shoud I worry about this? After restarting, I see that the changes in txt file have been saved.

Comment: No its only a warning. And when you launch Gedit from the launcher instead of the commandline you wouldn't even see this warning

Comment: Thanks for help. When I'm on the step in 12:55, and enter the command :$sqldeveloper,  I get a massage: /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper: line 5: cd: opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin: No such file or directory. -but I see folder bin when open the folder sqldeveloper-. I do this same as in the tutorial, so I thought that I can't run the command $sqldevloper, for these two errors. Maybe you have something idea for this error? If not I think, I should ask a new question.

Comment: You should be using a $ sign before a command, just type sqldeveloper. But a tip is just to look and listen very carefully how the person in the tutorial does it.